# Cauchy–Schwarz inequality (how to choose the components of the vectors U and V in general )

Tags: linear-algebra, inequality

$$xy+yz+zx=3$$

How can I show that $$ x+y+z$$ cant be **less** than 3 ie, 3 is the global minimum, using cauchy Schwarz inequality.

I prefer simple and detailed solution because I just begun on this topic.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You actually want to show $x+y+z\ge 3$ (e.g. $x=3/2$, $y=3/5$, $z=1$).

Comment: Thanks, Yes 3 is the global minimum . Ill edit it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using Cauchy Schwarz inequality

$3=xy+yz+zx \leq \sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2} \sqrt{y^2+z^2+x^2}=x^2+y^2+z^2$.

$(x+y+z)^2=x^2+y^2+z^2 +2(xy+yz+zx) \geq 3+6=9$

If the condition of $x,y,z\geq 0$ is added, we result in the conclusion.

If not, there is a counter example for $x,y,z = -1$.

Comment: Thanks alot , Can you give me an insight on how to tackle such problems? 
I mean does it come with practice or there are instructions on how to get grip on the expression we want to minimize ?

Comment: If you can understand several problems concerning some notions,thinking hard is most important for improving your insight.